# Why my VLOOKUP returns only #NA?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 Sheets :

On one Sheet1 I have a date value in column C2
And Sheet3 Where I have 3 fields :

> ```
> B2 -Start date   C2 - End date  D2 Period description  
> ..................................................... 
> B139 -Start date C139 - End date  D139 Period description
> ```

Now at  Sheet1 I want to have a period description for  date range period 
I have this formula `=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet3!$B$2:Sheet3!$D$134,3,TRUE)`

But I always get result #NA.
Why? All my ranges are unique

```
1/1/2011    1/31/2011   1
2/1/2011    2/28/2011   2
3/1/2011    3/31/2011   3
4/1/2011    4/30/2011   4
5/1/2011    5/31/2011   5
6/1/2011    6/30/2011   6
7/1/2011    7/31/2011   7
8/1/2011    8/31/2011   8
9/1/2011    9/30/2011   9
10/1/2011   10/31/2011  10
11/1/2011   11/30/2011  11
12/1/2011   12/31/2011  12
```

Comment: Your dates in either of the two tables might be formatted as Text. Is your lookup value in first column or second column? Does your table in Sheet2 start with Column B? You have mentioned Sheet2 but your formula refers to Sheet3. Please check if it's Sheet2 or Sheet3.

Comment: I try to lookup on the date that are between the ranges for 1st and 2nd column.

Comment: What value are you looking up for example, what's in C2 on Sheet1? Check if there are leading spaces in your date range table in Sheet3 or C2

Comment: In your example you state on Sheet1 you have those headers then on Sheet1 you have the formula, "VLOOKUP(C2,...)". If this is accurate, then your VLOOKUP formula is referencing the column header.

Comment: I've never seen a continuous range specified with the sheet name given twice. I suggest you use `Sheet3!$B$2:$D$134` instead of `Sheet3!$B$2:Sheet3!$D$134` However the problem is likely to be mismatched type, since dates can be tricky. To check that, you could try pasted a cell from your lookup reference table straight into the cell that is being checked.